# Web Reference is not updated after changed and update a web method

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, asmx

I've got a web method in asmx web service in vs 2012 that takes a single int parameter:

```
[WebMethod]  
public string FilterData(int a)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

After i add a new parameter into method:

```
[WebMethod]  
public string FilterData(int a, int b)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

I cannot invoke FilterData with two parameters, but with one parameter. I try to re-add reference and to recreate web service file, but i had not any solution to solve my problem.
I HOPE IN YOUR HELP..
thanks to all!

Comment: If the web service expects 2 parameters then you need to send 2 parameters. If there are edge cases where only 1 parameter is necessary then you should have 2 different asmx web services and you could factor out code repetitions into a different class, if necessary.

Comment: Did you deploy your changes to IIS ? Maybe you made a change in the code but did not deploy your changes to IIS hosting your web service that's why you are still getting old web reference proxy with just one parameter.

Comment: @Hakunamatata I am using local server.  How can update old webreferences ?

Comment: where do you invoke it from?

Comment: @DanielVorph i invoke from url web service

Answer (score 2):

To update the web reference proxy class, follow the instruction in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf3b21x2.aspx

It's a simple point-and-click operation in Visual Studio. The IDE will regenerate all the proxy class code for you.

Comment: I try to update web references but is the same. After I remove references and web services, and application is running and i can update, delete gridview records without web services. Is something about cache or something else ?